# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined when transferring event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When trying to run such code in the browser:

```
var k = function(e) {
    return e.clientX;
};
var abc = function() {
    alert(k());
};
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("click", abc);
```

Error is displayed :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientX' of undefined
```

With that, when I display the result of an event without transferring it to another function, everything works

```
 var k = function(e) {
     alert(e.clientX);
};
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("click", k);
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: You do not have `pageY` anywhere in the code in your question. Also, if `k` takes an argument, which it depends on, you should pass it an argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute

```
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("click", abc);
```

in function abc(), you will get event as param, so you can declare abc function like below,

```
var abc = function(event) {
    alert(k());
};
```

to get the desired result, you need to pass event to function k(), like below

```
var abc = function(event) {
    alert(k(event));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

`k` expects the event as an argument. You need to add that parameter to the `abc` function, and then pass it along when it calls `k`.

```js
var k = function(e) {
  return e.clientX;
};
var abc = function(event) {
  alert(k(event));
};
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("click", abc);
```

```html
Click on the text here.
```